# How to get column data inside cursoradapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, position

As a beginner, I made some test to get the id of a list in the listview. I display some logs when a user click a list. But im quite confuse on the result. the id and position is not consistent. Can someone explain and help me how to get the correct id ? this is code below.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class QuestionsCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Cursor c;
    private Context context;

    public QuestionsCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        this.c = c;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(final int pos, View inView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = inView;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.question_detail, null);
        }
    //  this.c.moveToPosition(pos);      

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        String senderName = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("msg_from_user"));
        TextView sender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMessage);
        sender.setText(senderName);

        String senderMessage = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("msg_message"));
        TextView message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvMessageSender);
        message.setText(senderMessage);

        v.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.d("adaptor cursor",""+ c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
                Log.d("adaptor position",""+ c.getInt(c.getPosition()));
                Log.d("adaptor position",""+ pos);
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //  AskdDatabaseHelper msg_db = new AskdDatabaseHelper(context);
            //  msg_db.deleteQuestion(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));

            //  cursor.requery();
            //  notifyDataSetChanged();
                return false;
            }

        });


        return(v);
    }
}
```

Comment: in getView use v.setTag(position), and in onLongClick(View v) you can call v.getTag() to get the position